# Difference between "usermod -aG" and "usermod -G" options

Tags: options, usermod

I'm preparing for the LPIC-1, exam 102, and was wondering what is the difference between these two commands with respect to options `-G` and `-aG`:

1. `usermod -G projectA, projectB jsmith`
2. `usermod -aG projectA, projectB jsmith`

The user `jsmith` has its own default group, which is not listed above among the groups/projects.

As I understand from the man pages of `usermod`, in (1) `jsmith` is taken off the listed  groups/projects. In (2), the user is appended to those groups listed after `-G` and this does not affect its belonging to its default group.

Do I correctly interpret the usage of these two options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`usermod -G` sets the user’s supplementary groups to *only* the groups specified; so after running

```
usermod -G projectA,projectB jsmith
```

the `jsmith` user will belong to `projectA`, `projectB`, and its “primary” group.

`usermod -aG` adds the specified groups to the user’s supplementary groups; so after running

```
usermod -aG projectA,projectB jsmith
```

the `jsmith` user will belong to `projectA` and `projectB` in addition to any groups it already belonged to (including its primary group).